# Set of Numbers with GCD equal to $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Can someone give me a set of $4$ positive integers with $3$ of them having a common divisor that is greater than $1$, but the GCD of all four positive integers is $1$.

Comment: $\{2, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: It is surprising to note that later answers have more votes, though they all refer to the same thing.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: That's not so surprising when you consider factors such as clarity and generality. I upvoted the answer that I thought had the best of both factors.

Comment: @RoryDaulton So if you wrote a short answer (in a hurry) to some question, and find a slightly more descriptive answer posted a minute later (most likely after reading yours), and having all the upvotes you deserved, would you find it fair?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: Short answer: Yes. Longer: I have had exactly that happen to me, and though I didn't like it I understood. The other answer may not have copied my ideas: it takes time to type a longer answer, and I have sometimes found myself giving "a slightly more descriptive answer posted a minute later" without having read the earlier answer. Also, if you are looking for "fair", a site like this that depends on votes is the wrong place to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you meant that for *any* triplet of the positive integers their $\gcd>1$ and the $\gcd$ of all of them is $1$, then the following works:

$$\{2\cdot 3\cdot 5,\:2\cdot 3\cdot 7,\:2\cdot 5\cdot 7,\:3\cdot 5\cdot 7\}$$

Answer (score 4):

Take $4$ primes $p,q,r,s$ and look at the numbers $prq,pqs,prs,qrs$ every three of which have a common divisor greater than $1$, but all $4$ have gcd $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take 4 distinct primes, $p, q, r, s$, and $a=pqr$, $b=pqs$, $c=prs$, $d=qrs$.